# The class 'OAuthBundle\Entity\Client' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-odm, fosoauthserverbundle

I did FOSOAuthServer as in documentation  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

but have exception:

```
Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException:
The class 'OAuthBundle\Entity\Client' was not found in the chain configured namespaces FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document

  at vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:37
  at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException::classNotFoundInNamespaces('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client', array('FOS\\OAuthServerBundle\\Document'))
     (vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain.php:112)
  at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\Driver\MappingDriverChain->loadMetadataForClass('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client', object(ClassMetadata))
     (vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php:159)
  at Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->doLoadMetadata(object(ClassMetadata), object(ClassMetadata), false, array())
     (vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:333)
  at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php:217)
  at Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager.php:286)
  at Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager->getClassMetadata('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory.php:24)
  at Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Repository\DefaultRepositoryFactory->getRepository(object(DocumentManager), 'OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (vendor\doctrine\mongodb-odm\lib\Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager.php:508)
  at Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager->getRepository('OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (vendor\friendsofsymfony\oauth-server-bundle\Document\ClientManager.php:39)
  at FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\ClientManager->__construct(object(DocumentManager), 'OAuthBundle\\Entity\\Client')
     (var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1780)
  at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosOauthServer_ClientManager_DefaultService()
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:335)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('fos_oauth_server.client_manager.default')
     (var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1820)
  at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosOauthServer_StorageService()
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:335)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('fos_oauth_server.storage')
     (var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1810)
  at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosOauthServer_ServerService()
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:335)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('fos_oauth_server.server')
     (var\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php:1790)
  at appDevDebugProjectContainer->getFosOauthServer_Controller_TokenService()
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php:335)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('fos_oauth_server.controller.token')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver.php:54)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver->createController('fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver.php:52)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver->createController('fos_oauth_server.controller.token:tokenAction')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver.php:95)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver.php:58)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:136)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel.php:171)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (web\app_dev.php:29)
  at require('C:\\www\\symfony\\web\\app_dev.php')
     (vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\Resources\router.php:42)
```

My entities placed in /src/OAuthBundle/Entity

Client

```
namespace OAuthBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\Client as BaseClient;

/** @Document(collection="oauth_client") */
class Client extends BaseClient
{
    /** @Id(strategy="AUTO") */
    protected $id;
}
```

AccessToken

```
namespace OAuthBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\Id;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations\ReferenceOne;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\ClientInterface;

/**
 * @Document(collection="oauth_access_token")
 */
class AccessToken extends BaseAccessToken
{
    /**
     * @Id(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ReferenceOne(targetDocument="OAuthBundle\Entity\Client")
     */
    protected $client;

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    public function setClient(ClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }
}
```

Other entities RefreshToken and AuthCodelike like this.

Application configuration:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: symfony_test
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true

fos_oauth_server:
    db_driver: mongodb
    client_class:        OAuthBundle\Entity\Client
    access_token_class:  OAuthBundle\Entity\AccessToken
    refresh_token_class: OAuthBundle\Entity\RefreshToken
    auth_code_class:     OAuthBundle\Entity\AuthCode
```

My composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle",
        "OAuthBundle\\": "src/OAuthBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

console:

```
$ composer dumpautoload
Generating autoload files


$ ./bin/console cache:clear --env=dev

 // Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug
 // true


 [OK] Cache for the "dev" environment (debug=true) was successfully cleared.
```

I do not understand where is problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the auto_mapping feature looks for entities under the Entity namespace, so given that your entity (FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\XXX) is not there, Doctrine does not know anything about it.

You need to configure entities of `FOSOAuthServerBundle` in your doctrine mapping by hand to add your custom entity namespace.

```
entity_managers:
        default:
            mappings:
                MyBundle:
                    type: annotation
                custom_mapping:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Document\
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/src/FOS/OAuthServerBundle/Document/"
                    is_bundle: false
```

Comment: Documentation says that: `Note: If you don't have auto_mapping activated in your doctrine configuration you need to add FOSOAuthServerBundle to your mappings in config.yml.` But I enable auto-mapping, This is not enough?

Comment: not enough look with attention at the doc (use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client as BaseClient;) Base client is in Entity namespace but your BaseClient is in Document namespace.

Answer (score 2):

This config works:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: symfony_test
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                custom_mapping:
                    type: annotation
                    prefix: OAuthBundle\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/OAuthBundle/Entity"
                    is_bundle: false
```